# Curves satisfying this functional

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-equations

This is a problem in Hartle's "GRAVITY":

Consider the functional

$$S[x(t)]= \int_{0}^{T} \left[\left(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right)^2 + x^2(t)\right]\text{ }dt$$

Find the curve $x(t)$ satisfying the conditions:

$x(0)=0$, and $x(T)=1$,

i.e make $x(t)$ an extremum, and find its extreme value: whether it is maximum or minimum.

Here's what I did: I evaluated the Euler lagrange equation :

$\frac {\partial {L}} {\partial x}$=$\frac{d}{dt}$ $(\frac {\partial L} {\partial \dot x})$,
where $L=\dot x^2 + x^2$, and obtained:
$$\ddot x=x$$.
Now, how do I solve this equation to do the rest of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you derived the correct equations of motion,

$$\ddot{x}(t)-x(t)=0$$

We make an *ansatz*, $x(t)=e^{rt}$ where $r \in \mathbb{C}$. Taking derivatives, and inserting them, we see,

$$e^{rt} \left( r^2 -1 \right)=0$$

Clearly $r=\pm 1$, and the general solution of the equation is given by,

$$x(t)=c_1e^{t} + c_2 e^{-t}$$

Now consider $x(0)=0$:

$$x(0)=c_1+c_2=0$$

hence $c_1=-c_2$. The other condition imposes,

$$x(T)=c_1 e^{T}+c_2 e^{-T} = 1$$

We have a system of two linear equations with two unknowns; in matrix form:

$$\left( 
\begin{matrix}
e^T & e^{-T} \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right) \left( \begin{matrix} c_1 \\ c_2\end{matrix}\right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Can you take it from here to determine the constants?

Comment: I already determined the constants, @JamalS. Thsnx anyways. Its +/-1/2cosht